# C Remove node from linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

How can I go about removing a node from a linked list?

Here is my code:

```
void RemoveNode(Node * node, Node ** head) {
    if (strcmp(node->state, (*(*head)->next).state) == 0) {
        Node * temp = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    Node * current = (*head)->next;
    Node * previous = *head;
    while (current != NULL && previous != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(node->state, (*current->next).state) == 0) {
            Node * temp = current;
            previous->next = current->next;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
        previous = previous->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

But I keep getting seg faults.

I feel like I'm doing something stupid.... Any ideas?

Comment: Why do `previous = previous->next` instead of just `previous = current` before reassigning current?

Comment: Also, if you get segmentation faults, run your program in a debugger. It will stop where you have your problem, and let you examine the callstack and variables. At least you should edit your question to include the callstack, and point out where in provided code the crash happens.

Comment: Also, do you *always* have a valid `(*head)->next` pointer? What if the list is empty? What if there's only one node in the list?

Comment: I don't understand the comparison with the 'next' nodes.  It seems like some nodes might be missed, and yes, possible running of the rails with a NULL next ptr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess:

```
void RemoveNode(Node * node, Node ** head) {
    if (strcmp(node->state, ((*head)->state) == 0) {
        Node * temp = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    Node * current = (*head)->next;
    Node * previous = *head;
    while (current != NULL && previous != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(node->state, current->state) == 0) {
            Node * temp = current;
            previous->next = current->next;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you pointed out what you've changed.

Comment: I changed comparision with the 'next' value to just the present value, and I changed the update of previous in the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you try doing this with recursion, to avoid the need for a "double pointer". It will extremely simplify the logic. [This link](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/linked-list/delete/) has a very good explanation and implementation of doing this recursively. This one specifically will even work if you attempt to remove a node from an empty linked list.

```
Node *ListDelete(Node *currP, State value)
{
  /* See if we are at end of list. */
  if (currP == NULL)
    return NULL;

  /*
   * Check to see if current node is one
   * to be deleted.
   */
  if (currP->state == value) {
    Node *tempNextP;

    /* Save the next pointer in the node. */
    tempNextP = currP->next;

    /* Deallocate the node. */
    free(currP);

    /*
     * Return the NEW pointer to where we
     * were called from.  I.e., the pointer
     * the previous call will use to "skip
     * over" the removed node.
     */
    return tempNextP;
  }

  /*
   * -------------- RECURSION-------------------
   * Check the rest of the list, fixing the next
   * pointer in case the next node is the one
   * removed.
   */
  currP->next = ListDelete(currP->next, value);


  /*
   * Return the pointer to where we were called
   * from.  Since we did not remove this node it
   * will be the same.
   */
  return currP;
}
```